# Javascript window location, skipping over dropdowns and applying style to span within a link

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using window location and vanilla javascript to create active menu links on my site and it works as far as matching the single item links to the active page and applying the style. However, it is applying it to any of the dropdown items as well.

How can I do this and avoid applying it to the dropdown items?

Also, how can I still match the href of the link, but apply the style to the span within the link instead of the link itself?

```js
    const activePage = window.location.pathname;
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('ul.navbar-nav li.nav-item a.nav-link').
    forEach(link => {
        console.log(link);
        if(link.href.includes(`${activePage}`)){
            link.classList.add('active');
        }
    })
```

```css
.nav-link span.active-pill{
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent" >
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/"><span>Home</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="productDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown"
               aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span>Products</span>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="productDropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-item p-2" href="/Products/test">test</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/FAQ"><span>FAQs</span></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is not an exact match so it will match anything that has that string in it. Still not sure what your problem is exactly.

Comment: The main problem is that I don't want the root drop down item to be colored differently at all, so avoided in the rule. But also I want to modify so that if the link anchor tag matches, I apply the style to the span within the link and not the link itself

Comment: So then you need to walk the tree up until you find the parent element, and then select the anchor and span

Comment: Ok I figured that out finally, but my biggest issue remains: The dropdown class line item links are also being affected at all times and on the home page all items are affected because my home page href is just "/" and all of my href targets start with that. Is there a better general way to strip them to match?